# Python. Best way to match dictionary value if condition true

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to build a parser now part of my code is looks like this:

```
    azeri_nums      = {k:v for k,v in zip(range(1,10),("bir","iki","uc","dord","beş","altı","yeddi","səkkiz","doqquz"))}
russian_nums    = {k:v for k,v in zip(range(1,10),("один","два","три","четыре","пять","шесть","семь","восемь","девять"))}
```

Imagine that I should find the digit if roomnum ="одна"
Here is how I trying to match this:

```
    if roomnum.isalpha():
    for key,value in azeri_nums.items():
        if value.startswith(roomnum.lower()):
            roomnum = str(key)
            break

if roomnum.isalpha():
    for key,value in russian_nums.items():
        if value.startswith(roomnum.lower()):
            roomnum = str(key)
            break
```

is there any other method to do that that will work faster, or some best practices for this situation?

Thank you in advance!

P.S.
the reason that this code works that module "re" capture from "одна" only "од" and that is why "один".startswith("од") returns true.

Comment: It looks like you should have your dictionaries map strings to ints, and not the other way around.

Comment: Does your current code work, though? if roomnum ="одна" then `"один".startswith(roomnum.lower())` won't be true.

Comment: BTW, there's a neater way to build those dicts, eg `dict(enumerate(("один","два","три","четыре","пять","шесть","семь","восемь","девять"), 1))`. However, as Christofer Ohlsson & Nf4r say, you probably should swap your keys and values, eg `{k:v for v, k in enumerate(("один","два","три","четыре","пять","шесть","семь","восемь","девять"), 1)}`

Comment: sorry I don't show you other part of my code. its my fault, the reason that this code works that module re capture from "одна" only "од" and that is why "один".startswith("од") returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dict to be

```
azeri_nums = {v.lower():k for k,v in zip(range(1,10),("bir","iki","uc","dord","beş","altı","yeddi","səkkiz","doqquz"))}
russian_nums  = {v.lower():k for k,v in zip(range(1,10),("один","два","три","четыре","пять","шесть","семь","восемь","девять"))}
```

And once you've names mapped to digits, just use:

```
key = None # By default
roomnum_lower = roomnum.lower()
if roomnum_lower in azeri_nums:
    key = azeri_nums[roomnum_lower]
elif roomnum_lower in russian_nums:
    key = russian_nums[roomnum_lower]
```

Dictionary is based on keysearch, not valuesearch. The first one is O(1) and allows u to use `key in dict` when the 2nd one is O(n) and requires looping.

## EDIT TO COMMENT:

if you want to map one word to others, create another dict that will handle it.

```
 string_map = {'одна': ['один',]} # map single string to many others if u want
```

And then all u need to do is:

```
key = None # By default
roomnum_lower = roomnum.lower()
if roomnum_lower in azeri_nums:
    key = azeri_nums[roomnum_lower]
elif roomnum_lower in russian_nums:
    key = russian_nums[roomnum_lower] 
if key is None:
    # At this point you know that the single string is not in any dict,
    # so u start to check if any other string that u assigned to it is in dict
    for optional_string in string_map.get(roomnum_lower, []):
        opt_str_low = optional_string.lower()
        key = azeri_nums.get(opt_str_low, None)
        key = russian_nums.get(opt_str_low, None) if key is None else key
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I should be specify the reason why I used .startswith:

Comment: value can be formed in several ways, for example:

Comment: "одна" should also map to "один", is it other way than using for statement? BTW sorry for multiple comment. its my first time here.

Comment: Edited answer with extra dictionary that would map a single value to others.